# How do I modify file access control lists using python?

Tags: python, acl, access-control, chmod

I have a script that does a whole bunch of file manipulation in python, but I'm running into trouble because I'm routinely encountering files that have ACL's set to things like "group: everyone deny delete".

For other permission issues I've used `os.chmod` to fix things, but can't find how to remove or modify ACL's using this, or other methods.

Comment: Did you try `os.chmod("/tmp/foo.txt", stat.S_IWOTH)` ? [source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm)

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibacl

Comment: yeah, I tried all sorts of permissions manipulation before I stumbled across ACL. None of my various testing worked so I'm sure it's the ACL settings. It works when I remove the setting through command line chmod, I'm just looking to see how it's done in python

Comment: just looked into pylibacl. It looks like what I need, except it seems to be linux only and I'm making this script cross platform. Though good starting point, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On **macOS** you can call directly `chmod`:

```
# exceptions: 
#   subprocess.CalledProcessError:
#       Command '['chmod', '-h', '-a', 'everyone deny delete', 
#                 '/Users/liviu/Music']' returned non-zero exit status 1
if 0:
    subprocess.check_call(['chmod', '-h', '-a', 'everyone deny delete', os.path.expanduser('~/Music')])

proc = subprocess.Popen(['chmod', '-h', '+a', 'everyone deny delete', os.path.expanduser('~/Music')])
proc.communicate()
```

I suppose there's a command line equivalent on **Unix-es**.
Now **Windows** is a different story, but you can always count on [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-6) .